# Why C++ don't have Java style type erased generics?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, type-erasure

Both Java generics and C++ templates have their advantages and disadvantages. Java generics produce less code and help minimize the size of executables whereas C++ rewrites entire template code for every different instantiations of a template. On the other hand, C++ templates support basic data types and even constant types as parameter argument whereas Java only supports classes as parameters for generics.

Why can't C++ have both? When user wanted to use the type inside a function, he could have used C++ style templates and otherwise he could have used Java style generics when declaring a parametric class/function. What technicality is preventing the implementation of this idea?

**EDIT**: For example consider this:

```
struct A {
    virtual void do_something() {}
};

struct B: public A {
    virtual void do_something() {}
};

template <typename T>
void call_do_something(T arg) {
    arg.do_something();
}

int main() {
    A a;
    call_do_something(a);
    B b;
    call_do_something(b);
}
```

```
class A {
    public void do_something() {}
}

class B extends A {
    public void do_something() {}
}

class Z {
    public static void <T extends A> call_do_something(T arg) {
        arg.do_something();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Z.call_do_something(new A());
        Z.call_do_something(new B());
    }
}
```

As to my knowledge, when compiled, the above C++ code would generate two versions of `call_do_something`, one for A and one for B. But an equivalent code below in java would produce only one `call_do_something`. This would reduce generated executable size.

I'm not saying that Java generics are better than C++ templates. I was just curious to know why this is not implemented in C++, is there a technical reason for that, was it proposed in the past etc. Sorry for the confusion.

---

**EDIT**: This question was asked when I didn't know in depth about these concepts. Now that I think I have a better understanding of templates in C++ and generics in Java, I am trying to answer this question myself.

Java generics can benefit by using type erasure because it has single rooted class hierarchy and objects are always passed by reference (note that types that are passed by value like `int` and `float` can't be used in generics). Java compiler erases the actual generic type of the type parameter and replaces it with the upper bound of the parameter. Java's generics is more related to runtime polymorphism in C++.

On the other hand, C++ templates can do much more than Java generics. It can do call by value, it can instantiate a template with two unrelated classes etc. But it can't implement type erasure because objects can be passed by value and when done, their sizes and substructures vary and a single machine code cannot handle them all.

But in a particular scenario, if you have a common base class, and you are passing objects by reference, then you should not be going for templates in C++. You should use runtime polymorphism with virtual functions instead.

The below generified code in Java is actually equivalent to:

```
class AList<E extends A> {
    private List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();

    public E add(E ele) {
        list.add(ele);
        return ele;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AList<B> l = new AList();
        B b = l.add(new B());
    }
}
```

this in Java:

```
class AList {
    private List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();

    public void add(A ele) {
        list.add(ele);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AList l = new AList();
        B b = (B)l.add(new B());
    }
}
```

and this in C++:

```
class AList {
private:
    std::vector<A&> vec = {};

public:
    A& add(A& ele) {
        vec.push_back(ele);
        return ele;
    }
}

int main() {
    AList l;
    B btemp;
    B& b = static_cast<B&>(l.add(&btemp));
}
```

**TL;DR** Type erasure is effective in Java generics since it has single rooted class hierarchy and objects are always passed by reference. Since these are not the case in C++, type erasure is not something that suits for C++ templates.

*I thought of putting this in answers. But since the question is closed, and I failed in my try to reopen, I am adding it here.*

Comment: you can do type erasure in C++ as well. Not clear what you are missing. If your question is why C++ does not use type erasure for standard containers, thats because there is not much benefit in doing so, but it has a cost

Comment: C++ has type erasure.

Comment: `Java's type erasure has clear advantages` [Citation Needed].

Comment: C++ is all about efficient abstractions _in that order_. Type erasure can be and is done in C++. See `std::any` and `std::function` for standardized examples.

Comment: @MikeVine *Java's type erasure has clear advantages* - [eerorika on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138911/why-c-dont-use-java-like-type-erasure-for-generics#comment116931493_66138911). In fairness, it also has clear disadvantages.

Comment: `Mainly Reduced Generated Code`. This has caveats. If the code for 2 instantiations of a template would generate exactly the same byte code then a compiler will probably share them (see opt:ICF). So C++ is as good as Java. If the code for an instantiation is different then by definition if you share instantiations you'll generate less efficient code for one of those. So C++ is better (faster) than Java in that case. So C++ >= Java (take this slightly tongue in cheek)

Comment: These days, code size isn't really an issue except on very limited systems. Can you think of an advantage that actually matters?

Comment: *"What's preventing this?"* I imagine compiler vendors are busy implementing other features. New standard/poc proposals. Idk if anyone ever proposed this to the C++ standards committee. No proposal would mean no compiler support.

Comment: @molbdnilo this is more nuanced. Code size does affect performance due to the fact that CPU cache is limited.

Comment: The function should be written as `void call_do_something(A& arg)`. A template isn't needed. Need a better example.

Comment: Either there is a reason (known, evaluated and documented), or not. This is not opinion based. I vote to reopen.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Thanks for voting. I had asked this question when I was fairly new to C++. During that time my opinion may have been biased. Now that I have read and understood more on the concepts, I have edited the question and hopefully it is fact-based now.

Comment: "You should use runtime polymorphism with virtual functions instead." - if you do not care about performance in this particular case - may be. However, using runtime polymorphism for a small performance-critical operation (such as reading one byte from stream) is a Big No-No...

Comment: @No-BugsHare Runtime polymorphism requires only one extra vtable lookup isn't it?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB IIRC, Stroustrup identified direct costs at two extra pointer indirections. And on modern CPUs, each indirection can cost you up to 200 CPU cycles, which is already pretty bad (heck, even L3 access is around 40 cycles IIRC). However, the largest negative of runtime polymorphism is that it effectively disables inlining around this call - and this can (and usually does) cost you A LOT (and while those RAM access cycles kinda go away if you call it in tight loop, costs of no-inlining are there forever and ever).

Answer (score 7):

What you perceive as advantage, other people might perceive as disadvantage. For example, type-erased access means that you pay performance penalty for access, and can not do static type checks at compile time.

There are type-erased function objects in C++ - `std::function`, so you could use those in your code, but bear in mind, there are disadvantages to this.

Comment: Apart from the limitations I mentioned in the question, what are the disadvantages? Erased types are always bound to a baseclass, and hence static checks can be done at compile time within that bound...  I may not be clear in explaining it here, but I am comparing with about java generics.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB since you asked in broad terms, I replied in broad terms. If you want more custom-tailored answer, you can provide a snippet in Java which you think produces the better code, and ask how to achieve same efficiency in C++.

Comment: As far as I know, creating a template function, and invoking it with two different classes, would result in two sets of generated code, each for each case. But If those two classes had a common ancestor, and function only depends on the members declared there, then using type erasure would reduce generated code size.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB generated code which is identical will likely be discarded during link-time optimization.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB for runtime polymorphism you need no generics or templates

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yes, sure.. that's why types are erased. But it would result in more compile time type safety.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB In your example just make it `void call_do_something(A& arg)`. Not sure what you mean with "more compile time type safety". btw sorry for spamming this answer ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I know, this may be the worst example... I was in hurry.. Now anyway question is closed... As you said, this may not be needed for C++. Let it be.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB it is needed sometimes and it can be done in C++. "What exactly is preventing this?" - nothing.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB "But If those two classes had a common ancestor, and function only depends on the members declared there, then using type erasure would reduce generated code size" - in C++, move the function to the common (non-templated) ancestor (where it actually belongs, as it depends only on its members) - and bingo! - less code size with no need for type erasure and associated costs. BTW, moving-code-to-common-ancestor (even if such a common ancestor has to be created just for this purpose) is a common trick widely used in std:: implementations since time immemorial.